# How to modify and debug CSS provided by third party

Tags: html, css

I'm a full-stack developer. But like many full-stacks I prefer back-end. During my career I've found that developers often tend to somehow outsource CSS jobs. In two ways basically - by hiring agency or by dedicating some person to handle CSS. In my opinion it's typical to create and improve some basic things, but if we encounter a complicated CSS problem - we just call agency or our front-end expert.

My question is about strategies for working with CSS project created by someone else. As long as one needs just to find a class which should be used for some element it's not a big deal. But when one starts to modify it - the big ball of mud begins to shake.

In back-end it's easy. If you break something heavily it won't compile. If you break something in a more subtle way - it'll be soon clearly visible and quite easy to debug because it will show you what is executed step by step. But when I start to modify CSS - oh god! - popular scenario is that I have something which works on a plain html document, but when I put it in some elements of bigger structure it stops working. And then hour after hour I'm sweating trying to localize line of CSS which caused it.

Do you know any methods, any strategies to make it easily?

Comment: you can debug it with browser tooks like "firebug" or "developer tools" that are part of the chrome browser.... not sure what you mean about if outsource it or not, thats not a direct technical question

Comment: Basically, the CSS for a site is a framework, and you are asking how to understand a framework written by another developer. And I'm sure you know that there are no magic tricks there, especially if the framework changes all the time. But anyway, a very important part of debugging web front end code is using the developer tools in the browser, the "inspector". There you can live debug the HTML and CSS, alter things and see what causes what.

Comment: @Roope I of course know mentioned tools and use them, though it's still a problem to search through tons of CSS. Well, I wanted to know some magic tricks :).

Comment: @Landeeyo Okay, well... :D Why do you need to search through tons of CSS? If you inspect the element on the web page, you see the applied CSS for that element. There you can live debug, check/uncheck stuff or change values, and when you find something that you would like to change, you can see the file name and line number in the inspector. So you should immediately know where to go without searching through tons of stuff? Or no?

Comment: The thing with UI development is that there is no way for a computer to know how things should look, obviously. So it is a bit hard to create automated debugging for UI stuff. You'll have to manually see that things look the way you want them to look. Front-end people are more like artists and designers, and coding is just the way to achieve those goals.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to modify the third party CSS, the classes you want to modify write them in your css file and apply !important after each attribute that is having a conflict with the third party css classes.

For example:

In 3rd party CSS there is a class:

```
.demo{
   width:100px;
   color:#666666;
}
```

Now you want to alter its width and font colors, so you write in your css like this

```
.demo{
       width:80px!important;
       color:#ff0000!important;
    }
```

**Hope this will help you, let me know any issues further and I can try to address that by giving some solution. Thanks**

Comment: I've heard about !important and it's of course useful. However I'm searching a way to rather find what exactly breaks our code, not overriding it.

Comment: Finding code that breaks, the best way is to use firebug, I don't think there are any automated tools that can bring down results for CSS classes that are breaking the code.. Its moreover a manual inspection

Comment: I would strongly discourage the use of `!important` as it breaks the specificity engine built in to the CSS. Instead, apply the same selector or a more specific selector. Remember too, that when two selectors are the same, the last instance will take precedence so applying your stylesheet after the third party one with the same selectors can also override the undesired styles.